# Horizontal concatenation of two array

Tags: javascript

how to do horizontal concatenation of two arrays in javascript?

```
var a = [[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]] 
var b = [7,8,9]
```

I want output like :

```
c = [[1,2,7], [3,4,8], [5,6,9]]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` and use `index` to access corresponding value from second array

```js
var a = [[1,2],[3,4], [5,6]] 
var b = [7,8,9]

let final = a.map((v,i)=> v.concat(b[i]))

console.log(final)
```